discord.py is launching but not responding to messages
import discord
from discord import Intents, Message, Client
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path
from random import randint

#launchingbetween
dotenv_path = Path('C:/Users/USER/OneDrive/phyton/discordbot/venv/bot/.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=dotenv_path)
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("the bot is here")

client.run(token=TOKEN)
#launchingbetween

@client.event
async def on_message(self, message=discord.Message):
    if message.content == "hi":
        await message.channel.send("hello")
    else:
        return

Everything other than the last 6 lines works. The message appears in terminal, bot becomes online. However, and the bot does not respond to messages; it does not give any errors, it just doesn't work. And it is not about permissions or anything; the bot used to work on the same server.

did you give the bot permission to read messages? Is reading messages part of the default intents?

yes it has all the permissions necessary


Your on_message method should be declared before the client.run.
self also have to be removed from the on_message, it would make sense if you were using cogs (you might want to take a look at these).
In order to explicit the variable type, you want to do on_message(message: discord.Message), with a : and not with an =.

Correct code:
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("the bot is here")

@client.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    if message.content == "hi":
        await message.channel.send("hello")
    else:
        return

client.run(token=TOKEN)


There's a small error made on the 'on_message()' function. The parameter message should not be set equal to discord.Message.
Instead this is how the line should look like:
async def on_message(message):

you are right but it still doesnt work for some reason

You should also remove the self parameter since you're not using cogs. The only parameter that should be there is message.

still doesnt work but i think you should know that the words content channel and send are not defined or connected to anything they are white coloured
